controlling servo motors using ROS2 , direction chaniging error
I am controlling two servo motors using single axis drive through modbus communication , normally the motor starts to rotate in a  clock wise direction , but i have to change the direction from clock wise to counter-clock wise but it doesn't respond ,
Here is my code :
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from pymodbus.client import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient
from pymodbus.exceptions import ModbusException
from pymodbus.pdu import ExceptionResponse
import time
import struct
class ModbusNode(Node):
def init(self):
super().init('modbus_node')
self.declare_parameter('port', '/dev/ttyUSB0')
self.declare_parameter('baudrate', 9600)
self.declare_parameter('timeout', 1)
    port = self.get_parameter('port').get_parameter_value().string_value
    baudrate = self.get_parameter('baudrate').get_parameter_value().integer_value
    timeout = self.get_parameter('timeout').get_parameter_value().double_value

    self.client = ModbusClient(
        port=port,
        baudrate=baudrate,
        timeout=timeout,
        parity='N',
        stopbits=1,
        bytesize=8
    )

    if not self.client.connect():
        self.get_logger().error('Failed to connect to the Modbus device.')
        return

    # Motor addresses
    self.motor_1_address = 1
    self.motor_2_address = 2

    # Command register 
    self.command_register = 40125
    # Jog velocity registers
    self.jog_velocity_high_register = 40343
    self.jog_velocity_low_register = 40344

def enable_motor(self, motor_address):
    self._write_register(self.command_register, 159, motor_address)
    self.get_logger().info(f"Motor {motor_address} enabled successfully.")

def disable_motor(self, motor_address):
    self._write_register(self.command_register, 158, motor_address)
    self.get_logger().info(f"Motor {motor_address} disabled successfully.")

def start_jog(self, motor_address):
    self._write_register(self.command_register, 150, motor_address)
    self.get_logger().info(f"Motor {motor_address} jog started successfully.")

def stop_jog(self, motor_address):
    self._write_register(self.command_register, 216, motor_address)
    self.get_logger().info(f"Motor {motor_address} jog stopped successfully.")

def set_jog_velocity(self, motor_address, velocity):
    # Validate velocity range
    if not (-24000 <= velocity <= 24000):
        self.get_logger().error(f"Invalid jog velocity: {velocity}. Must be between -24000 and 24000.")
        return

    # Convert the signed 32-bit velocity to two 16-bit values (high and low words)
    packed_value = struct.pack('>i', velocity)
    high_word, low_word = struct.unpack('>HH', packed_value)

    # Write high word to 40343 and low word to 40344
    self.get_logger().debug(f"Setting jog velocity {velocity} (high word: {high_word}, low word: {low_word}) "
                            f"for motor {motor_address}.")
    self._write_register(self.jog_velocity_high_register, high_word, motor_address)
    time.sleep(0.5)  # Delay to ensure stability
    self._write_register(self.jog_velocity_low_register, low_word, motor_address)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    self.get_logger().info(f"Jog velocity for motor {motor_address} set to {velocity}.")

def _write_register(self, address, value, motor_address):
    try:
        modbus_address = address - 40001  # Modbus address offset for holding registers
        self.get_logger().debug(f"Writing value {value} to Modbus address {modbus_address} "
                                f"(register {address}) for motor {motor_address}.")
        result = self.client.write_register(modbus_address, value, slave=motor_address)
        if isinstance(result, ExceptionResponse):
            self.get_logger().error(f"Failed to write to register {address} for motor {motor_address}: {result}")
    except ModbusException as e:
        self.get_logger().error(f"Modbus Exception: {e}")

def _read_register(self, address, motor_address):
    try:
        modbus_address = address - 40001  # Calculate Modbus address
        self.get_logger().debug(f"Reading Modbus address: {modbus_address} for motor {motor_address}")
        result = self.client.read_holding_registers(modbus_address, 1, slave=motor_address)
        if isinstance(result, ExceptionResponse) or not hasattr(result, 'registers'):
            self.get_logger().error(f"Failed to read from register {address} for motor {motor_address}: {result}")
            return None  # Return None if there's an error
        return result.registers[0]
    except ModbusException as e:
        self.get_logger().error(f"Modbus Exception while reading register {address} for motor {motor_address}: {e}")
        return None  # Return None if there's an exception//000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

def main(args=None):
rclpy.init(args=args)
node = ModbusNode()
while rclpy.ok():
    motor_input = input("Enter motor number (1, 2, or both) to control: ").strip().lower()
    if motor_input not in ['1', '2', 'both']:
        print("Invalid motor number. Please enter 1, 2, or both.")
        continue

    motor_addresses = []
    if motor_input == '1':
        motor_addresses = [node.motor_1_address]
    elif motor_input == '2':
        motor_addresses = [node.motor_2_address]
    elif motor_input == 'both':
        motor_addresses = [node.motor_1_address, node.motor_2_address]

    command = input("Enter command (enable/startjog/stopjog/setvelocity/disable/exit): ").strip().lower()
    if command == 'enable':
        for motor_address in motor_addresses:
            node.enable_motor(motor_address)
            time.sleep(0.5)  # Increased delay between commands
    elif command == 'disable':
        for motor_address in motor_addresses:
            node.disable_motor(motor_address)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    elif command == 'startjog':
        for motor_address in motor_addresses:
            node.start_jog(motor_address)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    elif command == 'stopjog':
        for motor_address in motor_addresses:
            node.stop_jog(motor_address)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    elif command == 'setvelocity':
        velocity = int(input("Enter jog velocity (-24000 to 24000): ").strip())
        for motor_address in motor_addresses:
            node.set_jog_velocity(motor_address, velocity)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    elif command == 'exit':
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid command.")

rclpy.shutdown()

if name == 'main':
main()
